# Why don't SQL Server instances always show up in enumeration?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get SQL Server instance(s) running on my PC.

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   SqlInstanceCollection.Items.Add(row["ServerName"].ToString() + "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString());
   SqlInstanceCollection.Text = SqlInstanceCollection.Items[0].ToString();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes I get the instance while sometimes I don't, even when server is running.

How long should it take to get a list of the instances of running SQL Servers?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if the [sql browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) is running, does that affect whether your code finds the running instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from MSDN:

> Due to the nature of the mechanism used by SqlDataSourceEnumerator to
>   locate data sources on a network, the method will not always return a
>   complete list of the available servers, and the list might not be the
>   same on every call. If you plan to use this function to let users
>   select a server from a list, make sure that you always also supply an
>   option to type in a name that is not in the list, in case the server
>   enumeration does not return all the available servers. In addition,
>   this method may take a significant amount of time to execute, so be
>   careful about calling it when performance is critical.

[SqlDataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSources Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources.aspx)

so as stated in their notes, method is unreliable by design ;) strange!

**EDIT:** If I had to solve a similar problem I would try to use the windows API NetServerEnum with proper parameter set. It's really not trivial but should be more reliable.

Comment: Will you please suggest another way to accomplish this job?

Comment: I suggest using NetServerEnum as more reliable way, surely more complicated also :(